# Get child categories using eBay API

Tags: php, ebay-api

I need to get all child categories from eBay using their API. I wrote the code below, but it's only getting root level category. Can anybody guide me how I can get sub categories of parent categories.

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
 }

 $url= 'http://open.api.ebay.com/Shopping?callname=GetCategoryInfo&appid=3b5sdsdsdsd&siteid=0&CategoryID=1&version=949IncludeSelector=ChildCategories';  
 $xml = curl($url);
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
 print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution :) here is the link for that [example code in this link](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getcategories.html)